# Startx not running due to missing shared libraries

Tags: linux-mint, shared-library, startx

I was deleting some files and accidentally deleted a shared object file `libXdmcp.so.6`. Now startx won't run. Is there a way I can recover the system from the terminal. I am using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the package that provides a file with `apt-file find`. You may need to install it first with `apt-get install apt-file`.

```
apt-file find libXdmcp.so.6
```

That will show that it is provides by the package `libxdmcp6`.

```
libxdmcp6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
libxdmcp6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
```

To reinstall the package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libxdmcp6
```

Comment: The apt-file was not installed. I tried apt-get using the last statement , but didn't work. I had an ISO lying around. So copied the file from that into my os. Now works fine.

Comment: @NaveedUnjum If you don't have apt-file, you'll have to install it with `apt-get`. I've added this to my answer.